# USB TO SATA CIRCUIT do it yourself

Tags: linux, hard-drive, laptop, motherboard, sata

Ok so i thought this I have a laptop and a internal hdd and a working motherboard.

So if i connect my `hard disk to sata port of motherboard`

And connect laptop USB-USB wire in motherboard USB will my Hard Disk work in laptop ?

`LAPTOP -> Motherboard USB --- Motherboard SATA <- Hard disk`

Comment: Ok. You don't seem to understand how this works. You can't build a USB to SATA circuit DIY easily, and that's because it requires a controller to convert those signals from SATA to USB (or reversed). And to make things worse, you can't buy the chip separately from a local store. The easiest solution is to get yourself a new adapter from Ebay (already built by somebody else), as they are very cheap and easy to find.

Comment: I hope that real Mr. Trump wouldn't do such experiments...

Comment: As for the actual question (i guess), there is a special USB male - USB male cable for connecting two computers together for file sharing. The motherboard's internal USB port is just like another external USB host port, so that does not help.

Comment: @Alex He probably has no idea at all about these things. At least he can an employee at his own hotel :D

Comment: It is possible, but: (1) you will need to buy a USB-USB comms cable, at a price similar to a USB-SATA adaptor (any other cable is liable to cause electrical damage to both the laptop and the motherboard); (2) you will need a CPU and memory in the motherboard so as to run an OS which will support USB networking; (3) you need to load USB networking software in the laptop; then (4) in the laptop you can mount the hard disc as a network drive with consequent performance. Why would you want to do all this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not work as asked, for at least two reasons:

1. Just connecing an USB cable this way will not turn the other laptop motherboard into an USB to SATA converter. (You can share the HDD from that laptop, usually via Ethernet but possibly also via and USB to USB sort of connection, but you will need to configure some software for that. It will not work automagically).
2. Normal USB comes in master and slave mode. This is also why USB has two very distinct connectors. You can connect a master to a slave, but not two slaves or two masters. This is why there are no USB-A to USB-A cables

---

Some extra notes:

There is an USB to USB cable which actually is USB-A to "device which acts as a slave Ethernet - bridge- Second device which act as USB ethernet to USB master 'cable". Obviously this is not a mere cable, even though salesdroids may present it as such.

Second extra notes. Some USB ports can work as both master and as slaves. There are commonly only found on mobile phones with a micro-USB AB connector. They are **not** the default on a random USB port of a motherboard.